# Counting Number of Points Satisfying given Equation

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry

I am given set of points *S*. I need to find the count of four vertices (A, B, C, D) satsfying the equation AB + CD = BC + AD, morever, the vertices should be pairwise distinct.

Here, A, B, C, D denotes the vertices choosen from set S.
AB, BC, CD, AD denotes the distance between A and B, B and C, C and D, and A and D respectively.

I could come up with an algorithm of O(N^4). Is there any more optimal solution?

Example :
S = {(3, 0), (0, 4), (7, 3), (4, 7)}
Ans = 8
These are the indexed of S which satisfies the given equation

1 2 4 3
1 3 4 2
2 1 3 4
2 4 3 1
3 1 2 4
3 4 2 1
4 2 1 3
4 3 1 2

Comment: What does it mean to multiply two 2D points?  What does AB mean if A,B are points?  Where did you encounter this problem?  Can you credit the source of the problem in your question?